# Scala - Generics, covariant type and function as parameter

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to make a generic way of building `<table>` from a List of objects in Play Framework.

I wanted to create a class `ColumnInfo` representing columns metadatas :

```
case class ColumnInfo[T](name: String, value: T => Any)
```

The `name` field represents ... well, the name of the column, and the function `value` should take an object in parameter, and return a value for that column.

Let's say I have a model `User`, extending an other class (or trait, whatever) `Bean` :

```
case class User(name: String, age: Int) extends Bean
```

I then create a Play Framework template name `list.scala.html` that takes a `List[Bean]` and a `List[Column[Bean]]` as parameters, and displays the corresponding `<table>` :

```
@(list: List[Bean], columns: List[ColumnInfo[Bean]])

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        @for(c <- columns) {
            <th>@c.name</th>
        }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @for(obj <- list) {
        <tr>
        @for(c <- columns) {
            <td>@c.value(obj)</td>
        }
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In my controller's Action, I should have something like this :

```
object ListController extends Controller {

  def list = Action {
    val users = List(
        User("foo", 20),
        User("bar", 30)
    )

    val columns = List(
        ColumnInfo[User]("Name", _.name),
        ColumnInfo[User]("Age", _.age)
    )

    Ok(views.html.list(users, columns)
  }
}
```

The problem is that I can't put a `ColumnInfo[User]` in a List of `ColumnInfo[Bean]` !

That's normal. But if I make the type `T` in `ColumnInfo` covariant, it tells me that :

```
case class ColumnInfo[+T](name: String, value: T => Any)

covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type => (T) => Any of value value
```

Logic. But what can I do then ? I also tried with lower bounds, by adding an other type `U` to `ColumnInfo`, like `[+T, U >: T]`, but it only brought me other errors.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a `ColumnInfo[User]` is not a `ColumnInfo[Bean]`. For example, if you have

```
val myInfo = ColumnInfo[User]("MyCol", user => user.name)
val myBean = new Bean
myInfo.value(myBean)
```

There's no way this can possibly work, since `myBean` has no `name` method (even if we could force it to compile, it would fail at run-time), so the compiler catches this and throws it out.

In fact, `ColumnInfo` appears to be contravariant in `T` (anything that goes into a function is contravariant, for the reasons demonstrated in the example - in some languages, they actually use the keyword `in` for contravariance, to make this clear).

You could therefore define `ColumnInfo` like:

```
case class ColumnInfo[-T](name: String, value: T => Any)
```

Unfortunately, this limits re-use of your template, as its signature has to be `@(list: List[User], columns: List[ColumnInfo[User]])`

In an ideal world, templates would support type parameters, like regular Scala methods, so you could have a signature like `@[T](list: List[T], columns: List[ColumnInfo[T]])`. However, [Play templates do not currently support type parameters](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/5H5dI29Gt8s).

I can see two ways around this

### Existential Types

We can hack around it with existential types. We'll wrap up our arguments to the template into an invariant case class:

```
case class TableData[T](list: List[T], columns: List[ColumnInfo[T]])
```

and change the signature of the template to:

```
@(cols: TableData[T forSome {type T}])
```

We now have to change `list` to `cols.list` and `columns` to `cols.columns` in our template to match up.

We can call our template like:

```
// In ListController...
Ok(views.html.list(TableData(users, columns)))
```

### Casts

Alternatively, we can cast around the problem. Give your template a signature of:

```
@(list: List[Any], columns: List[ColumnInfo[Any]])
```

and cast `columns` to `List[ColumnInfo[Any]]` when you actually call it:

```
// In ListController...
Ok(views.html.list(users, columns.asInstanceOf[List[ColumnInfo[Any]]]))
```

This will compile, as Scala uses type erasure. And provided `list` is actually a `List[User]`, the types will be correct at run-time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, you made my day ! The second solution (using casts) works like a charm, but it seems that the first one doesn't : I get the following error : `type mismatch; found : List[models.ColumnInfo[models.User]] required: List[models.ColumnInfo[T forSome { type T }]]` Any idea why it tells me this ?

Comment: My best guess as to why the first option didn't work is that the compiler couldn't prove that `T` was the same in `list` and `columns`. Perhaps your list contains things that are not `Users`, or type inference has chosen an unsuitable type, like `List[Any]` or `List[Serializable]`?

Comment: When I will be able to check this, I will tell you ;) Nevertheless, the second solution is working well, so I validate your answer !